# Get request failed on RestSharp and works on postman

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp

I made a simple call ran over postman and over RestSharp.
the same request received bad response over RestSharp.

the Url

> https:PATH/rest/ids?request_id=6d3a4f28-633c-440c-8631-905710e9302d

Postman response - 200 with the answere in the body.
headers:
[image]

Rest sharp code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://PATH/rest/ids?request_id=6d3a4f28-633c-440c-8631-905710e9302d");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response5 = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The response:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
   <title>Error 500 </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
  <p>Problem accessing /rest/ids. Reason:
  <pre>    Server Error</pre></p>
  <hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking.
adding the header `request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*")`
have resolved the issue.